# using 'AND' with COUNT(*)

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

I would like to get the total number of entries, upon 2 or more conditions.
Yet is seems as if mysql is ignoring the 'AND' clause in the query.

***edit***:
I want to get number of calls made by user with id=97, while the date is between starttime and stoptime, and prefix is like *us*

Example:

```
select count(*)
  from calls
  where id = 97 
  and starttime >= '2012-06-11'
  and stoptime >= '2012-06-12'
  and prefix like '%us%'
```

This gives me total amount of calls from id=97, while ignoring the rest of the conditions

Comment: Besides you forgot the quotes around `%us%`

Comment: It doesn't ignore it. More like your conditions are so that only `id` matters

Comment: Did you mean `or` instead of `and`? Should one of the conditions meet or all of them?

Comment: I edit the question to hopefuly be clearer

Comment: @NitsanBaleli . . . Sample data and desired results would help clarify what is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that you want the second condition on the date should be `<=`:

```
select count(*)
from calls
where id = 97 
  and starttime >= '2012-06-11'
  and stoptime <= '2012-06-12'
  and prefix like '%us%';
```

You should also know that if you are storing *times* in the date time field along with the date, the you might really want:

```
select count(*)
from calls
where id = 97 
  and date(starttime) >= '2012-06-11'
  and date(stoptime) <= '2012-06-12'
  and prefix like '%us%';
```

or better yet:

```
select count(*)
from calls
where id = 97 
  and starttime >= '2012-06-11'
  and stoptime <= '2012-06-13'
  and prefix like '%us%';
```

Comment: I understand now that the problem was a typo, and using 'AND' with COUNT is no problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think you meant to do something like

```
select count(*)
  from calls
  where id = 97 
  and (starttime >= '2012-06-11' and stoptime <= '2012-06-12')
  and prefix like '%us%'
```